# Exporting to CSV with a specified variable in "WHERE" clause

Tags: ruby-on-rails, where-clause, export-to-csv

I'm trying to create a list of links that take the supplier name in the link, and export the data with that supplier name. I know what i've put in the model at the moment is wrong, i'm just not sure how to pass the supplier in properly.. sorry if this is vague, here's the code i have so far:

Controller

```
def export_supplier    
@software = Software.find_supplier
software = CSV.generate do |csv|

# for the headers of the csv file
  csv << ["Quantity", "Item Number", "Item Description"]
  # the chosen rows from the database
  @software.each do |s|
    csv << [s.amount, s.productcode, s.description]
  end
end
send_data(software, :type => 'text/csv', :filename => 'software.csv')
end
```

View

```
<% @softwares.each do |l| %>
<li>
    <%= link_to "#{l.supplier}", :controller =>'softwares', :action => 'export_supplier'%>
</li>
<% end %>
```

Model

```
def self.find_supplier
find_by_sql("SELECT s.productcode, s.description, CAST(SUM(l.amount) as UNSIGNED) AS amount
FROM softwares s
LEFT JOIN licenses l ON s.id=l.software_id
WHERE s.supplier = #{l.supplier} AND l.amount > 0
GROUP BY s.supplier, s.vendor, s.title, s.edition")
end
```

Comment: checkout your code you are iterating software not supplier,you may want to get for individual software supplier? what you want actually

Comment: no i want it to iterate the suppliers in the software table, which it does

Answer (score 0):

`<%= link_to "#{l.supplier}", :controller =>'softwares', :action => 'export_supplier',:supplierid=>l.supplier.id%>` or

if routes is member route

`<%= link_to "#{l.supplier}", export_supplier_software_path(software,:supplier_id=>l.supplier.id%>)`

if routes is collection route

`<%= link_to "#{l.supplier}", export_supplier_softwares_path(:supplier_id=>l.supplier.id%>)`

Comment: there is no such thing as supplier id, supplier is just a field in the software table..